# Android Studio webview can not show MJPG ip webcam

Tags: android-studio, webview, stream, raspberry-pi, mjpeg

I am working on Android Studio and I want to show ip webcam in my app. I am following this link [1](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted) however it's working virtual device on android studio but when i build apk's folder and install my phone I am only see white blank page. I trying to change webView.loadUrl(..) exp. google.com or stackoverflow.com  and i get succesfull result both of  environment (my device and virtual env.)  How can I solve this problem thank you.

```
     WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);   
     webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);      
     webView.loadUrl("http://i.p.add.ress/?action=stream");                
     webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
```

Comment: can you share the url or working example url ?

Comment: 192.168.2.11:8080/?action=stream